npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6 and npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3 when installing @vscode/vsce
When I try to install @vscode/vsce with
npm install -g @vscode/vsce I have two warnings
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported

What is the criticality of these warnings and is there a way to get rid of them?

You can't get rid of them, you have to wait for the maintainers of VSCE (or one of the transitive dependencies you have via it) to stop using deprecated packages.
